# Matrix multiplication not working when I store the result of a sum instead of accessing that element on each sum

Tags: c, for-loop, indexing, matrix-multiplication

I am writing a [blocked matrix multiplication algorithm](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/autoblock/node2.html) for n x n matrices. My matrices are stored as 1D arrays. My first version of the algorithm works fine:

```
double * blocked_ijk_matmul(double *A, double *B, int n, int b) {
    double *C = (double *) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
    int i_block, j_block, k_block, i, j, k;

    for (i_block = 0; i_block < n; i_block += b) {
        for (j_block = 0; j_block < n; j_block += b) {
            for (k_block = 0; k_block < n; k_block += b) {
                for (i = i_block; i < fmin(i_block + b, n); ++i) {
                    for (j = j_block; j < fmin(j_block + b, n); ++j) {
                        for (k = k_block; k < fmin(k_block + b, n); ++k) {
                            C[(i * n) + j] += A[(i * n) + k] * B[(k * n) + j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return C;
}
```

However, in this algorithm `C[(i *n) * j]` is computed quite a large number of times depending on the size of the matrices. If I instead try to store this sum, and then set the value of `C[(i *n) * j]` to the total sum value when all summations are complete, I get incorrect results:

```
double * blocked_ijk_matmul(double *A, double *B, int n, int b) {
    double *C = (double *) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
    int i_block, j_block, k_block, i, j, k;

    for (i_block = 0; i_block < n; i_block += b) {
        for (j_block = 0; j_block < n; j_block += b) {
            for (k_block = 0; k_block < n; k_block += b) {
                for (i = i_block; i < fmin(i_block + b, n); ++i) {
                    for (j = j_block; j < fmin(j_block + b, n); ++j) {
                        double sum = 0;
                        for (k = k_block; k < fmin(k_block + b, n); ++k) {
                            sum += A[(i * n) + k] * B[(k * n) + j];
                        }
                        C[(i * n) + j] = sum;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return C;
}
```

I cannot figure out for quite some time why this is not working. Clearly, `double sum = 0;` and `C[(i * n) + j] = sum;` need to be placed somewhere else, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: Are the values stored in your C array ever initialized to zero before you start summing into them?

Comment: I just realised not, but strangely that is the algorithm that gives the correct result. I am very confused now

Comment: The first example `C[(i * n) + j] += ... `is clearly wrong (or unlucky), because the memory provided by `malloc` has uninitialised values. Perhaps use `calloc`?

Comment: I understand what you're explaining, but I have tested it several times and it is working perfectly

Comment: No, it is not "working perfectly".  "Testing several times" is not adequate to prove perfection.  Assign all elements of `C[]` to 0.0 first.  Then use in the loops.

Comment: `fmin(double x, double y)` for finding the minimum of 2 integers is poor use of mixing a FP function with integer math - although I doubt that is the problem (unless `<math.h>` was not included.

Comment: What are the values of `n,b` used in `blocked_ijk_matmul()`?

Comment: I have set `n = 2` and `b = 1` for testing, but in practice they would be in magnitude of thousands. I have changed the `malloc` to `calloc` too.